# What's the difference between visit X and before { visit X} in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am starting to learn TDD with rspec and Capybara using Rails 4. So far it's going really well. I have a question though.

When I want to test a certain page if it has the correct title, I write:

```
describe "page information" do
  before { visit root_path }
  it { should have_title(full_title('Test title')) }
end
```

But if I change `before{ visit root_path }` to `visit root_path`, it will raise an error. Why is this? In other tests I don't have to write `before X`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean literally you change this:

```
before { visit root_path }
```

to

```
visit root_path
```

If so, that's not a valid spec.  You're not inside a spec, so you can't use the `visit` method yet.

The `describe` block is not the beginning of a spec, like `it` is.  All `describe` does is add a nested message for the specs within it.

`before` and `after` are used to extract setup and tear-down steps so you can just assert things without repeating yourself.